# Bounds on the difference of correlated random variables

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics, bounds

Given two highly correlated random variables $X$ and $Y$, I'd like to bound the probability that the difference $ |X - Y| $ exceeds some amount:
$$ P( |X - Y| > K) < \delta $$

Assume for simplicity that:

- The correlation coefficient is known to be "high", say : 
  $ \rho_{X,Y}= {covar(X,Y)} / {\sigma_X \sigma_Y}  \geq 1 - \epsilon $
- $X,Y $ are  zero mean: $ \mu_x = \mu_y = 0 $
- $-1 \leq x_i, y_i \leq 1$ (or  $ 0 \leq x_i, y_i \leq 1$ if
  that's any easier)
- *(If it makes things easier, let's say $X,Y $ have identical variance: $\sigma_X^2 = \sigma_Y^2  $)*

Not sure how feasible it is to derive a bound on the difference given only the above information (I certainly couldn't get anywhere). A specific solution (if any), mandatory additional restrictions to impose on the distributions, or just advice on an approach would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even without those simplifying assumptions, a bound can be obtained by combining a couple of usual tools:

- The [variance of the difference of two correlated variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142745/what-is-the-demonstration-of-the-variance-of-the-difference-of-two-dependent-var/142759). It allows us to turn a two variables problem into an univariate problem.
- [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Statement). It puts a bound on the probability of exceeding a given value.

In some detail:

$$\sigma^2_{X-Y}=\sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Y-2·cov(X,Y)$$

$$cov(X,Y)=\sigma_X·\sigma_Y·\rho_{XY}$$

$$\sigma^2_{X-Y}=\sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Y-2·\sigma_X·\sigma_Y·\rho_{X,Y}$$

According to Chebyshev's inequality, for any random variable $Z$:

$$ \Pr(|Z-\mu|\geq k\sigma) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$$

Then (and using that $\mu_{X-Y}=\mu_X-\mu_Y)$:

$$ \Pr(|X-Y-\mu_X+\mu_Y|\geq k·\sqrt{\sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Y-2·\sigma_X·\sigma_Y·\rho_{X,Y}}) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$$

We can use the proposed simplifying assumptions to get a simpler expression. When:

$$\rho_{X,Y}= {covar(X,Y)} / {\sigma_X \sigma_Y}  = 1 - \epsilon $$
$$\mu_x = \mu_y = 0$$
$$\sigma_X^2 = \sigma_Y^2 = \sigma^2$$

Then:

$$\sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Y-2·\sigma_X·\sigma_Y·\rho_{X,Y} = 2·\sigma^2·(1-(1-\epsilon)) = 2\sigma^2\epsilon$$

And therefore:

$$\Pr(|X-Y|\geq k·\sigma\sqrt{2\epsilon}) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$$

Interestingly, this result holds even if $\epsilon$ is not small, and if the condition for correlation changes from $=1-\epsilon$ to $\geq 1-\epsilon$, the result doesn't change (because it's already an inequality).