# Why is the sum of two variances is larger than two times the covariances?

Tags: variance, covariance

I saw the following inequality:

$$
\sigma_{X_1}^2 + \sigma_{X_2}^2 \geq 2\sigma_{X_1X_2}
$$

and the brief explanation said that it is based on [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Probability_theory). But I couldn't make the connection. Why is the equation above is true?

Comment: Well, I'd have said it's implied by $\text{Var}(X_1-X_2)\geq 0$ but it sounds like that's not intended to be used here. Going from Cauchy Schwarz should be straightforward though; write the relevant expectations for each term in your equation and identify appropriate vectors $u$ and $v$ in those, and apply the inequality.

Comment: @Glen_b I couldn't see that, thanks. [THIS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/306117/41166) is an explicit demonstration of what you've said I believe.

Comment: If you apply Cauchy Schwarz, directly, you could consider whether writing $u$ as an expectation involving $X_1$ (and so on for other terms) would get you there.